# How to compare a date with year with one without year in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'd like to apologise if this has already been answered, but in 20 minutes of searching, I found nothing. I am using SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) and a stored procedure for creating a report with a query.

In the procedure, I have 2 parameters - `fromdate` and `todate`, that represent an interval. I must compare the dates of the rows selected, but I do not have to look at the year. For example, when I select an interval of 15-feb-2014 to 15-mar-2014, and one of the rows has a date column which value is 25-feb-2000, the report should display it. This can happen when we want to display a person's birthday, thus ignoring the year.

The problem is that if I just use

```
WHERE date BETWEEN @fromdate AND @todate
```

it will not display the row as apparently the year is taken into account.

Help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: After getting 2 possible solutions, I'm still wondering if there's an easier method than writing so complex logic. I'm shocked how hard it is to perform a date comparison, ignoring the year.

Answer (score 1):

you can write your where clause something like this...

```
WHERE 
   (MONTH(DateColumn) >= MONTH(@fromdate) AND DAY(DateColumn) >= DAY(@fromdate))
AND
   (MONTH(DateColumn) <= MONTH(@todate)   AND DAY(DateColumn) <= DAY(@todate))
```

Comment: Try `WHERE 
   (MONTH(DateColumn) = MONTH(@fromdate) AND DAY(DateColumn) >= DAY(@fromdate) OR MONTH(DateColumn) > MONTH(@fromdate))
AND
   (MONTH(DateColumn) = MONTH(@todate)   AND DAY(DateColumn) <= DAY(@todate)   OR MONTH(DateColumn) < MONTH(@todate))`. The downside of this solution is that it doesn't allow an `Index Seek` (if there is an index on `DateColumn`).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Events(
    EventID     INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    EventDate   DATE NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
GO

-- This index is neccesary in order to get [Index] Seek
CREATE INDEX IX_Events_EventDate 
ON dbo.Events (EventDate)
-- INCLUDE ([Description], ...)
GO

INSERT dbo.Events VALUES ('2000-01-25', 'X')
INSERT dbo.Events VALUES ('2000-02-25', 'Y')
INSERT dbo.Events VALUES ('2000-03-25', 'Z')
INSERT dbo.Events VALUES ('2014-01-25', 'A')
INSERT dbo.Events VALUES ('2014-02-25', 'B')
INSERT dbo.Events VALUES ('2014-03-25', 'C');
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers (Num INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY);
GO
-- It generates all numbers between 1 and 1000
INSERT dbo.Numbers 
DEFAULT VALUES 
GO 1000

-- My proposal / solution
DECLARE @FromMonth TINYINT, @FromDay TINYINT
DECLARE @ToMonth TINYINT, @ToDay TINYINT
SELECT  
    @FromMonth = 2, @FromDay = 15,
    @ToMonth = 3, @ToDay = 15;

SELECT  ev.EventID, ev.EventDate
FROM 
(
    SELECT  StartDate   = DATEADD(DAY, @FromDay - 1, DATEADD(MONTH, @FromMonth - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, 99 + n.Num, '19000101'))),
            EndDate     = DATEADD(DAY, @ToDay - 1, DATEADD(MONTH, @ToMonth - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, 99 + n.Num, '19000101')))
    FROM    dbo.Numbers n
    WHERE   n.Num <= 15 -- It generates all intervals from 2000 to 2014
                        -- You should change 15 with a propper values (ex. you could compute this values thus: 2014 - 2000 + 1)
                        -- If you want all intervals from 1990 to 2014 you should use (1) 89 + n.Num and (2) n.Num <= 25
) intervals 
INNER JOIN dbo.[Events] ev ON ev.EventDate >= intervals.StartDate AND ev.EventDate <= intervals.EndDate
```

If there is an [covered index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) on `EventDate` column then the execution plans will contain an `Index Seek`:

[image]